# Creating a getter for specific Directory visual C#

Tags: c#, directory, getter

I'm relatively new to **Visual C#** and I have been searching for a bit now. I cant find an actual solution to my problem (perhaps because i'm searching for the wrong way or thing).

So I want to create a getter that gives me the directory so I can convert the path name to a string.

This is the code I am using
(I already know that `getDirectories` gives an array of strings)

```
 public Directory getDBDirectory() {
   Directory db;
   if (!Directory.Exists(itemFolder)) {
      Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find directory.. is it created?");
   } else {
      db = Directory.GetDirectories(itemFolder);
   }
   return db;
 }
```

Comment: You know, thar [Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a **static** class, right?

Comment: I guess you want to return the path, so return a `String`. But doesn't make sense either because `itemFolder` is already that path. Can you tell us what you actually want?

Comment: When getting the path of the folder you might want to use the static class [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory is a Static Class. I assumes you need to get all folders inside `itemFolder`.
So just change the return type to `string[]` instead, like this:

```
public string[] getDBDirectory() {
  //Directory db; //no need
  if (!Directory.Exists(itemFolder)) {
     Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find directory.. is it created?");
     return null;
  } else {
    return Directory.GetDirectories(itemFolder);
  }
}
```

or if you just want to check if it exist:

```
public string getDBDirectory() {
  if (!Directory.Exists(itemFolder)) {
     Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find directory.. is it created?");
     return null;
  } else {
    return itemFolder;
  }
}
```

or if I understand you right, you can use `Directory.CreateDirectory(itemFolder)`; that will `Create If Not Exists`.

Comment: Wow, I literally feel stupid now.. I am thinking so far of the topic that i want visual C# to do it for me even though i already defined what the return was.... 
Thanks! This is it(2nd );

Answer (score 2):

To get the path for subdirectories:

```
string[] db = Directory.GetDirectories(itemFolder);
```

If you want to get Directory Info:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(somepath);
```

which you can access its name nad path by `dir.Name` and `dir.FullName`